# Is there a procedural way of finding a Möbius transformation given prescribed conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Is there a procedural way of finding a Möbius transformation given prescribed conditions?

For example, I've been asked to find a Möbius tranformation which fixes $\mathcal{C}_2$, maps $\mathcal{C}_1$ to a line parallel to the imaginary axis, and sends $4$ to $0$.  (Here $\mathcal{C}_r$ denotes the complex circle with radius $r$, e.g. $\mathcal{C}_1$ is the unit circle.)

I'm less concerned about solving this particular problem as I am about figuring out if there is a more or less algorithmic way to go about problems of this type.  I am aware that a Möbius transformation is completely defined by three points, but I'm not sure how to get this from the set images.

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, this seems like an over-determined problem. But there's some symmetry. Do you know what Möbius transformations map the unit disk to itself? Then can you generalize to the disk of radius $2$? Then think about how to get $4$ to map to $0$.

Comment: I figured out that the Mobius transformations fixing the unit disc are $e^{i\theta}\frac{z+a}{\overline{a}z+1}$ but I can't figure out how to generalize to the disk of radius 2.

Comment: Good start. Presumably there's some condition on $|a|$ there that you need in order to guarantee that the interior maps to the interior. What if you want the exterior to map to the interior and vice-versa? ... Can't you now rescale the problem to get it to work for a disk of radius $2$?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the best way to solve these types of problems is by using the [cross ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio)